# Per File Permisions With Git

Tags: git, github, permissions

I will be starting a new project shortly and am trying to figure out the best way to setup the git repo. I will have 2 teams. Non-restricted and restricted, the issue I am trying to solve is that I want to set file permissions for the restricted team which will limit them to only being able to commit to certain files inside the repo. Also when a restriced team memeber pulls the repo down I want to replace certain files with auto generated dll's. Basically the restricted team is outsource labour which i dont fully trust and thus dont want them being able to commit to all files within the repo, and also dont want them being able to see the "secret sauce". The non-restriced team should have read/write access to all files.Any ideas how to accomplish this?

It looks like google's repo could do the trick?

Comment: Gitolite has a feature for this called [VREF](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html). However, this will not let you "hide" the secret recipe.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it is possible to forbid access to some files or folders by setting up git hooks, but this doesn't seem to be a good solution IMHO for your case. If you are in the start of the project consider splitting your project to modules so that to keep them in different repositories if it's possible. Let's say one repository for local developers with the core of the system which contains the "secret sauce" and second for modules which are dependent on core libraries and can be outsourced. Then you can build core libraries nightly, obfuscate them and share with outsource developers.